# java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException : no match

Tags: mqtt, bouncycastle, keystore, keytool, aws-iot

I am facing one issue while integrating AWS Iot SDK in my Xamarin.Android app.
I am creating basic app just to connect to mqtt through AWS Iot to subscribe to topics and and publish messages to that topic.

I am getting "java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException:no match" in getTempKeystore method in AWSIotKeystoreHelper class.
I have created a bks file using bouncycastle which has both certificate and key.(I have created this certificate through AWS resource)

I have followed the exact same steps as mentioned in the link:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AndroidPubSub

Here is my code:

```java
    private static String CUSTOMER_SPECIFIC_ENDPOINT = "";
    private static String COGNITO_POOL_ID = "";
    private static String AWS_IOT_POLICY_NAME = "";
    private static Regions MY_REGION = Regions.UsEast2;
    private static String KEYSTORE_NAME = "";
    private static String KEYSTORE_PASSWORD = "";
    private static String CERTIFICATE_ID = "";
    clientId = UUID.RandomUUID().ToString();
        credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
        Android.App.Application.Context, // context
        COGNITO_POOL_ID, // Identity Pool ID
        MY_REGION // Region
    );

        Region region = Region.GetRegion(MY_REGION);
        mqttManager = new AWSIotMqttManager(clientId, CUSTOMER_SPECIFIC_ENDPOINT);           
        mqttManager.KeepAlive = 10;
        AWSIotMqttLastWillAndTestament lwt = new AWSIotMqttLastWillAndTestament("my/lwt/topic", "Android client lost connection", AWSIotMqttQos.Qos0);
        mqttManager.MqttLastWillAndTestament = lwt;

        mIotAndroidClient = new AWSIotClient(credentialsProvider);
        mIotAndroidClient.SetRegion(region);
        keystorePath = FilesDir.AbsolutePath;
        keystoreName = KEYSTORE_NAME;
        keystorePassword = KEYSTORE_PASSWORD;
        certificateId = CERTIFICATE_ID;
            if ((bool)AWSIotKeystoreHelper.IsKeystorePresent(keystorePath, keystoreName))
            {
               if ((bool)AWSIotKeystoreHelper.KeystoreContainsAlias(certificateId, keystorePath, keystoreName, keystorePassword))
                  {               
                    clientKeyStore = AWSIotKeystoreHelper.GetIotKeystore(certificateId, keystorePath, keystoreName, keystorePassword);
                  }`
               else
                  {
                    Log.Info(LOG_TAG, "Key/cert " + certificateId + " not found in keystore.");
                  }
            }
            else
            {
               Log.Info(LOG_TAG, "Keystore " + keystorePath + "/" + keystoreName + " not found.");
            }`
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue.I was using openssl pkcs12  to convert the certificates and keys into .p12 format. And then using the bouncycastle jar to convert the .p12 keystore to .bks format as android supports only BKS format. Instead of using bouncycastle i used [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/).I referred to the following links for all the further conversion process :

- Downloading portecle

  http://certificate.fyicenter.com/942_Portecle_Downloading_and_Installing_Portecle_1.7.html
- Conversion from .p12 to .bks

  http://portecle.sourceforge.net/change-keystore-type.html